# Leak in NSMutableArray category that returns array filled with NSNull

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

I currently have a NSMutableArray category that creates a NSMutableArray propagated with NSNulls. When I run this code in Instruments it tells me I have a leak here (read comment to see where)

```
#import "NSMutableArray+NSNull.h"


@implementation NSMutableArray (NSNull)

-(id)initWithNullCapacity:(int)capacity{

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        //Leak on [self init]
        NSMutableArray *array = [self init];

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            [array addObject:[NSNull null]];
        }
        self = array;
    }
    return self;
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is where I invoke the method:

```
#import "TWVStatData.h"
#import "NSMutableArray+NSNull.h"

@implementation TWVStatData

@synthesize creationTime;
@synthesize graphs;
@synthesize elements;
@synthesize type;

-(id)init{
    if(self == [super init]){
        type = -1;

        creationTime = [[NSDate alloc] init];

        graphs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithNullCapacity:3];
        elements =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not creating a sub-class of NSMutableArray, just adding a category, therefore calling [super init] will call the NSArray and not the NSMutableArray initializer, whetever it does which i would call just in case it does something important.

Also, as Ravin mentioned, setting self =  without calling [self release] first will leak the previous object, which was returned from the alloc call one level up in the call stack.

This is what you should do:

```
-(id)initWithNullCapacity:(int)capacity
{
    self = [self initWithCapacity:capacity];
    if (self) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < [self count]; i++)
        {
            [self addObject:[NSNull null]];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: When I do what you suggest, Instruments tell me I have a leak on line self = [self initWithCapacity:capacity];

Comment: @Cyprian could you post the code that uses this method? There really shouldn't be anything wrong with it...

Comment: you are right I had an error initializing an object higher in a hierarchy and not releasing it causing the object on the lower and to be leaking.

Answer (score 3):

This is going to be tricky, primarily because of how `NSArray` works underneath.  I would recommend doing this:

```
- (id)initWithNullCapacity:(NSUInteger)capacity {
  NSMutableArray *nulls = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
    [nulls addObject:[NSNull null]];
  }
  return [self initWithArray:nulls];
}
```

I think the problem is stemming from the assignment to `self`, though I'm not sure of that.  `NSArray` does some funky optimizations under the hood, and so I would avoid calling an `NSArray` initializer until *after* you have all your data ready to go.

Comment: When I run your code in Instruments I get a lick on line return [self initWithArray:nulls]; After trial and error I was managed to fix it with the implementation I posted as an answer.

Comment: @Cyprian then you're doing something wrong, because when I use this in an isolated manner, it works perfectly with no leaks.

Comment: +1 looks good, but i suppose the price is holding 2 arrays in memory instead of one for a while, not that i think it's going to cause any real implications

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will because at first line

```
self = [super init];
```

you are creating one object(`self`) and at `self = array;` you are de-referencing `self` and reassigning it. so earlier value is in leak.

Comment: Thanks, but can you explicitly tell me what to change in the method?

Answer (score 1):

```
-(id)initWithNullCapacity:(int)capacity
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            [self addObject:[NSNull null]];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

should do the job

Comment: Well when I do that the compiler gives me an error: -[NSMutableArray count]: method sent to an uninitialized mutable array object